# JavaScript Development in ES6 With Debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, babeljs

I have been trying to find a way to write ES6 JavaScript code, with real-time debugging features.

The problem is that ES6 code needs transpiling before browsers can interpret it (easy with babel), thus making it hard to work with debugging breakpoints.

**I found these two articles helpful:**

1. [how-to-debug-es6-nodejs-with-vscode](https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-debug-es6-nodejs-with-vscode-8d00bd6c4f94)
2. [debug-es6-code-in-node-js](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/10/29/debug-es6-code-in-node-js/)

**My question:**

What are skilled JavaScript developers doing about the above issue these days? Any of the three below?

1. Writing in ES6, transpiling it with babel/webpack upfront, and then trying to debug the new and messy ES5 code
2. Somehow synching the ES6 original code with the transpiled ES5 generated code, using source maps, to make debugging work
3. Not writing ES6 code at all

Comment: Source maps are the solution. When properly added, transpilation becomes an implementation detail

Comment: Modern browsers support ES6 natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a few hours on the same exact challenge myself, in Visual Studio Code.

I won't take credit for solving it, praise for that goes to Dustin Callaway. You can find simple step by step instructions in his medium article [here](https://medium.com/@drcallaway/debugging-es6-in-visual-studio-code-4444db797954).

**In summary (debugging transpiled code in Visual Studio Code):**

- Visual Studio Code (VSC) does not run any code. Node runs the code and VSC adds debugging features on top
- VSC scans the source file for breakpoints when launching the debugger
- It then uses a source map to find out where in the running code the breakpoints belong and thus where Node should stop
- Babel can watch your code for changes and re-compile as necessary real-time

---

Dustin's instructions let you debug ES6 files real-time in Visual Studio Code.

Whenever you are ready for production, just recompile and bundle with Babel and Webpack.

Comment: What led you to the conclusion that "*Node cannot run ES6 natively*"?

Comment: There is no JavaScript engine yet that natively supports ES6 modules. Not even the V8 engine in Chrome and Node.js. import/export being an example.

Comment: Are you [sure](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/) [there](http://2ality.com/2017/09/native-esm-node.html)?

Comment: Interesting. I do not think I would feel comfortable fully relying on it though. I would be concerned about backward compatibility and having to write special code for it. At least after transpiling I can be certain it won't give anyone any issues.

Comment: @Bergi As seen here: http://node.green/, you are right that pretty much all of ES6 is supported in node.js `8.9.x`, which runs JavaScript engine `6.1.534.xx` (v8). The site does show the backward compatibility concern though. I have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Most commercial projects I've worked on in the last few years have been set up so you write ES6 code, use Webpack, Babel/ Babel-Loader, with source-maps enabled.

Debug easily then in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Thanks dashton. So you actually compile/transpile it first, then debug the ES4 code afterwards? Isn't that hard as the code is more convoluted than the original you wrote?

As a side note, I have been using visual studio code and I like the editor and the IntelliSense. The task and launch setups are absolutely horrible though. I've spent two days trying to learn it and still haven't grasped it.

Comment: I found this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps 

That's more or less what you are doing?

Would you not have to go back and re-compile and reupload, every time you make a small change during debugging?

Comment: You would run webpack and have it watch file system; then any code changes you make get transpiled to ES5. With source-maps enabled in webpack and dev-tools you can then break-point and step-through your ES6 code. There are many how-tos on the web about setting up webpack, babel, and source-maps. This one is pretty good; http://blog.xebia.com/unlocking-es2015-features-with-webpack-and-babel/

Comment: Yes, the link you posted is what I'm doing. The point is you can make webpack watch for changes, so it automatically re-transpiles the changes. As the project gets bigger, your webpack set-up can be optimised to improve the watch performance. watch details : https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Answer (score 0):

Source maps seem to be the simplest way for debugging code, for me at least.